# What does it mean to speak of was and when?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

> We passed upon the stair       
> **We spoke of was and when**       
> Although I wasn't              
> there He said I was his friend

The above is the lyrics of the song "The Man Who Sold the World" of David Bowie. What does "speaking of was and when" mean?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. The interpretation of lyrics or poetry, or other literary analysis, is not on-topic here, as there is usually no single definitive answer—the lyricist may not have intended it to have any meaning at all, and just liked the way the words sounded when put to music. There are any number of sites devoted to discussion of the meaning of lyrics, among them Genius.com, SongMeanings.com, or indeed LyricInterpretations.com. At a basic level, this is a poetic way of saying "we mentioned/discussed/referenced things from the past, and how long ago/for how long it existed or endured."

Comment: @choster  -  I agree that song lyrics are a poor way to learn English - they routinely break the rules. I think it's probably fair to ask in case the phrase might be idiomatic. As collins is new to ELL, I think we can give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We spoke of was and when

This is not an idiom. It is a phrase invented by the songwriter. In general you will not learn normal spoken or written English by studying the lyrics of songs. They may be poetic, they may even be nonsense. They are rarely normal spoken or written English.

In this particular case we can assume that the people were talking about things that happened in the past (what was) and the times at which those events occurred (when).